# How to incorporate a continuity of 1st derivatives at an internal interface in a 2nd order Poisson equation in finite elements method?

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions

How should I modify the following matrix formulation of a finite element (FE) approximation of Poisson equation at the (internal) interface denoted by the nodes $i-1$ to $i+1$ having a continuous 1st derivative $\epsilon_1 \nabla\cdot U_1 = \epsilon_2 \nabla\cdot U_2$ at the internal interface nodes (say from $i-1$ to $i+1$)?

$$\begin {bmatrix} 
\epsilon_1 K_{11} & \epsilon_1 K_{12} & \epsilon_1 K_{13} & \dots & \epsilon_1 K_{1N}\\
\epsilon_1 K_{21} & \epsilon_1 K_{22} & \epsilon_1 K_{23} & \dots & \epsilon_1 K_{2N}\\
\vdots\\
\epsilon_1 K_{(i-1)1} & \epsilon_1 K_{(i-1)2} & \epsilon_1 K_{(i-1)3} & \dots & \epsilon_1 K_{(i-1)N}\\
\epsilon_1 K_{i1} & \epsilon_1 K_{i2} & \epsilon_1 K_{i3} & \dots & \epsilon_1 K_{iN}\\
\epsilon_2 K_{(i+1)1} & \epsilon_2 K_{(i+1)2} & \epsilon_2 K_{(i+1)3} & \dots & \epsilon_2 K_{(i+1)N}\\
\vdots\\
\epsilon_2 K_{N1} & \epsilon_2 K_{N2} & \epsilon_2 K_{N3} & \dots & \epsilon_2 K_{NN}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin {bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
\vdots\\
u_{i-1}\\
u_i\\
u_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_N
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin {bmatrix}
f_1\\
f_2\\
\vdots\\
f_{i-1}\\
f_i\\
f_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
f_N
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. Is your problem in 1D? What does $\epsilon$ stand for? Do yo want $C_1$ continuity in your formulation?

Comment: The short answer is Discontinuous Galerkin. We have not yet finished the tutorial, but is working code http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/tutorial_plate.html; you also might find something in deal.ii.